# Jquery individual toggle not working correctly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have the follow code which expands and hides all the content on expand and collapse. The problem I am facing is that that the individual items are not closing correctly. They should work correctly in FF and IE.

Problem is when all is expanded and you close one individually.. it closes a second one even though you havent clicked on the second one . there is some inconstancy.Try closing the last one or the second last one couple times after expanding everytime and you will it closes a 2nd  random item or the one next to it

It doesnt happen all the time. The problem is noticeable in firefox

I would really appreciate your help.

Here is the code below and fiddle and screen grab

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/rtxmpq8h/46/)

Javascript

```
    var prevId;
    function showDiv(id) {
        var infoDiv = "#" + id + "-moreinfo";
        var plusDiv = "#" + id + "-plus";
        var minusDiv = "#" + id + "-minus";

        if($(infoDiv).is(":visible")){
            removeHash();
            $(plusDiv).show();
            $(minusDiv).hide();
            $(infoDiv).slideUp(200);
        }else{
            window.location.hash = id;
            $(minusDiv).show();
            $(plusDiv).hide();
            $(infoDiv).slideDown(250);
        }
        if(prevId != undefined){
            if(prevId.valueOf() != id.valueOf()){
                $("#" + prevId + "-moreinfo").slideUp(200);
                $("#" + prevId + "-plus").show();
                $("#" + prevId + "-minus").hide();  
            }   
        }
        prevId = id;
    }

    /***
     *  removeHash()
     *  Initiates an HTML5 feature to clean URL hashes.
     *  Requires HTML5 Standards or IE10 or higher. Safe fallback for older browsers.
     **/
    function removeHash(e){ 
        /* pushState adds to the browser history, or replaceState which keeps the history uniformly clean */
        if (history.replaceState){
            /* HTML5 browsers, including IE10+ */
            history.replaceState("", document.title, window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
        } else {
            /* Other browsers */
            window.location.hash = '';
            return false;

        }
    }

        /***
     *  isNumber(value)
     *  Boolean function checking if value is numerical.
     **/
    function isNumber(n){
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }



/***
*   Manupulates CSS to show  css butons on expand and close. Also, expands and closes all violations


**/


    $(document).ready(function(){

        if (window.location.hash) {
            /* Clean the hash, stripping out the preceding symbol, as showDiv() needs numbers */
            var clean_hash = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
            var text = $(this).text();
            console.log("text "  +text);
            console.log("clean_hash "  +clean_hash);
            console.log("text " );
            /* Check if the hash is a number before attempting to expand */
            if (isNumber(clean_hash)) {
                showDiv(clean_hash);
                /* tiny wait before scrolling */
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    /* Uses jquery.scrollto library: http://balupton.github.io/jquery-scrollto/ */
                    //Scroll down to the item's h3 violation header text.
                    $('#post-'+prevId+' h3.viol-header').ScrollTo({
                        duration: 350,
                        easing: 'linear',
                    });
                }, 800);
            }
        }



         /**
          **   This shows the content when  the user clicks on Expand all and also switches the plus and minus
          **/
           $("#Hide").hide();
           $("#Show").click(function(e){
                 removeHash(e); //Reset the hash
                $("div.moreinfo").slideDown(200);
                $("div.plus").hide().removeClass("closed");;
                $("div.minus").show().addClass("opened");
                $("#Show").html("Expand All").addClass("expanded");     
                $("#Show").hide();
                $("#Hide").show();
                e.preventDefault();              
            });

         /**
          **   This code hides the ontent when  the user clicks on Expand all and also switches the plus and minus
          **/
            $("#Hide").click(function(e){
                removeHash(e);  //Reset the hash
                $("div.moreinfo").slideUp(200);
                $("div.plus").show().addClass("closed");    ;
                $("div.minus").hide().removeClass("opened");    
                $(".message").html("Collapse All");  
                $("#Show").show();
                $("#Hide").hide();

                e.preventDefault();          
           });


    });
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to work fine if you load your code in the right place http://jsfiddle.net/rtxmpq8h/47/

Comment: The problem i am facing is if you notice when you expan all. and try to close them individually.. sometimes the others also close. how cna that be corrected?

Comment: I'm not seeing that behavior in Chrome.

Comment: The behavior only happens in Firefox

Comment: Working fine in FF for me as well.

Comment: @j08691 -
Problem is when all is expanded and you try to  close one individually.. it closes a second one even though you havent clicked on the second one . there is some inconstancy. Try closing the last one or the second last one and you will it closes 2 items.

It doesnt happen all the time. The problem is noticeable in firefox

Comment: Works fine in Firefox DE.

Comment: @RobertRozas - try Expanding first and then try 2 to 3x to close the last one or the second last one. and you will see it still closes a 2nd item. instead of just itself in firefox.

Comment: @user244394, i made the same test...works fine...which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Steps to recreate this issue: Expand all > Collapse 1 Div > Collapse All > Expand All. Then collapse a different div. It should collapse that div and the first div that you collapsed. Can recreate this in any browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's retaining the previous `prevId` from before the Show All/Expand all was clicked. You will need to reset that `prevId` to `undefined` when the Show All/Expand All buttons is clicked.

I added this line to the top of your `$("#Show")` and `$("#Hide")` click functions and it seems to be working.

```
 prevId = undefined;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rtxmpq8h/54/

**Steps to recreate this issue:**

Expand all > Collapse 1 Div > Collapse All > Expand All. Then collapse a different div. It should collapse that div and the first div that you collapsed. I am able to recreate this in any browser.

Comment: Thank you. that seem to have  fixed the Firefox issues

Comment: You're welcome. Keep in mind though, I was able to recreate this issue in any browser. Check out the latest edit with the "Steps to recreate".